# Is it possilble to save an image list to a file?

Tags: c++, mfc, imagelist

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a CImageList object and save it as a file, so that I can use it in other projects, and if so how do I save it?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with CImageList, but if the images are loaded into memory, I believe treating them like a chunk of bytes and saving them to a binary file should be an option.

Comment: Have you looked at `CImageList::Write()`?

Comment: @zett42 I didn't entirely understand it when I saw it (i'm still a beginner really). I'll look at CArchive and and try and work it out.

Comment: It isn't hard, and the documentation provides an example of using CArchive for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cimagelist-class?view=vs-2019#write

Answer (score 1):

As explained under [Manipulating Image Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/manipulating-image-lists):

> You can write the image information to an archive by calling the [Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cimagelist-class#write) member function, and read it back by calling the [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cimagelist-class#read) member function.

A [CArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/carchive-class) can be backed by any stream, including a file stream. The documentation for [CImageList::Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cimagelist-class#write) provides complete sample code on how to serialize an image list to disk:

> ```cpp
> // Open the archive to store the image list in.
> CFile myFile(_T("myfile.data"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite);
> CArchive ar(&myFile, CArchive::store);
>
> // Store the image list in the archive.
> m_myImageList.Write(&ar);
> ```